# How can i set cipher suites for a Azure Application gateway with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

how can i set cipher suites for a Azure Application gateway with terraform? I did not find an element

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: What should i try, when there is not element exisiting in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-application-gateway-sslpolicy-custom/azuredeploy.json#L224) you need to define an `sslPolicy` property for the application gateway, which is missing in terraform. you can only choose ssl protocols to use: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_gateway.html#disabled_ssl_protocols

github issue to track: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1536

Comment: Thanks, i found this issue https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1536